# How to use rotated text labels in GeoServer based on attribute value?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I have several text layers in GeoServer, which are now shown as point layers with tiny graphic size and with labels (As mentioned in my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25070/text-layer-styling-in-geoserver)). All thses labels are, as expected, drawn horizontal. But I want them to be drawn at an angle, available in corresponding database table. 
I can not use simple **rotation** property, since it rotates all the labels at a specific angle.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Rotation tag together with a PropertyName which lets you draw the label based on an angle specified in a corresponding database table:

```xml
<Rotation>
    <ogc:PropertyName>rotation_column</ogc:PropertyName>
</Rotation>
```

You can see more about rotation and labeling here:

[Labeling in GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#rotation)