# Is it possible to draw labels behind other layers

Tags: geoserver, labeling, layers

According to my information, GeoServer always draws all labels at the end, over all other layers.  Can we configure a label so that it lies behind another layer for example with surface geometries?

So far our attempts have failed...

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible. So, why did you want to do that (as the GeoServer developers went to quite a lot of trouble to put labels always on top so people could see them)? it is possible there is some other way to achieve the effect you want

Comment: I believe https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25070/text-layer-styling-in-geoserver is closely related to your problem, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The aim is to "cover" unwanted areas in the map for reports in order to receive "island maps" from certain administrative districts.
In the meantime we have found a solution: Via the following parameter in the SLD of the layer, which should overlap the labels:

```
<VendorOption name = "labelObstacle"> true </VendorOption>
```